# Why does remeshing punch a bunch of holes in my model?

Tags: modeling, remesh

I'm currently working on a model I made in the 'modeling' tab, and went over to sculpting to sculpt it. When I did I couldn't actually make any direct modifications to it, but I (think I) found a way around that via remeshing. Unfortunately when I remeshed the model, it punched a thousand giant holes into it and I've been desperately attempting to patch all of them manually after my attempt to Generate>Solidify didn't work to help clean the mesh up. Any ideas on what I could do to remesh or fix this quickly? Link below is to a google drive dump of my model.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xZOL8XeZgprLt1A7rgPtJXzbQgOuXjxS/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reduce the number of subdivisions on your modifier from 5 to 2. Apply both modifiers. Use Remesh under Object Data properties (underlined below) and do a Voxel Remesh with a smallest voxel size of 0.05 (any smaller and you risk using up all your memory and crashing blender - so save a backup first regardless) - you don't need to go that small, you can stick with the default value if you like. Don't forget to hit the Voxel Remesh button when you're all set up. End result is like this:

[image: Vmesh]